# C++ - Visual Studio 2013 gives me the LNK 1168 error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

we are forced to use visual studio this year instead of netbeans  and i get the LNK 1168 error when i try compile a simple hello world programm.
I already used google and found that the "Application Experience" should not be turned off. 
It was on manual so i switched it to automatic and it still gives me the error.

Turning on "Application Expierience" seems to be working for everyone expect me.

```
Error   1   error LNK1168: cannot open C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\PAD1_02\Debug\PAD1_02.exe for writing C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\PAD1_02\PAD1_02\LINK PAD1_02
```

A copy&paste of the error.

I'm not a native speaker so i might have messed up some things but i'm pretty sure this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMwpr.png
is the "Application Experience" and it's on auto.

Any tips are welcome, greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `task manager`.

It seems the file `C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\PAD1_02\Debug\PAD1_02.exe` is still running while you are trying to re-build your application!

Try killing the process manually and try again!